How to add Kotlin-kapt plugin in android studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 2
I am using android studio version Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 2. I am trying to add kapt plugin for dagger hilt .Please help me regarding how to add kapt plugin in project root level and module level. and how to add depedencies of dagger hilt.

The internet is full of examples that you could try. What exactly isn't working as expected? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] and explain in more detail what the problem is. Please also check other questions on Stack Overflow, it is likely this was already answered. And lastly, why do you want to use kapt in the first place? Why not use KSP instead?

Adding dependencies
First, add the hilt-android-gradle-plugin plugin to your project's root build.gradle file:
plugins {
 ...
 id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.51.1" apply false
}

Then, apply the Gradle plugin and add these dependencies in your app/build.gradle file:
  plugins {
  id("kotlin-kapt")
  id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
  }

  android {
  ...
  }

  dependencies {
  implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.51.1")
  kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.51.1")
  }

  // Allow references to generated code
  kapt {
  correctErrorTypes = true
  }

Refer for more details
Dependency injection with Hilt

I have added the above code in my project still issue is not resolved. I am using Android studio version of Koala. and in Kolala version the version catalog is default.
